# How to prevent MsDepSvc.exe from starting?

Tags: windows, iis

Apparently, IIS7 is interfering with my apache server. To be more precise, it's claiming port 80. Killing MsDepSvc.exe fixes it, but I'd like to prevent MsDepSvc.exe it form starting in the first place.

Anyone who knows how to do that?

Comment: IIS is a web server, of course it will claim port 80. If you don't want two web servers on your system, You can uninstall one of them.

Comment: Point is, I want both of them. I set IIS to listen at port 8080 in stead of 80, but somehow port 80 is reserved and can't be used by Apache.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case you haven't solved the problem yet, or for anyone looking for the answer: MsDepSvc.exe is process of the Web Deployment Agent Service. You can control it's startup mode from the Services console (services.msc), for example.

Answer (score 2):

I knew these answers were right , but my services.msc was not showing the services, however this did the trick:

```
sc stop "MsDepSvc" 
sc config "MsDepSvc" start= disabled
```

Comment: Thanks ! My services.msc did not show MsDepSvc, but it started every time after computer start. This solved it

Answer (score 1):

To stop it manualy:

sc stop "MsDepSvc"

To disable it from startup:
Go to **services -> Web Deployment Agent Service** -> properties->startup->disable

now port 80 will be free

Answer (score 0):

You could also assign multiple ip addresses to your server and assign each one of them to a different http server. In network adapter settings select ipv4 protocol/properties/advanced... and add additional ip's. You might need some help of your ISP to provide you with multiple static public IP's.
then for apache, configuration is done in httpd.conf and for iis, change the ListenOnly registry entry and in IIS Manager, edit the 'Bindings' of ur websites.
As a newbie it took me days to figure this out. Hope this helps.